# Create UserCustomAction for SharePoint Framework Extensions (Tenant-Scoped)

Tags: sharepoint-framework, spfx-extensions

I have created a SPFx Extension (Application Customizer - Tenant Scoped) and I have uploaded it to the App Catalog succesfully.

Now I'm trying to add it in a Site creating a UserCustomAction, but I'm getting the next error:

> 'ClientSideComponentId and ClientSideComponentProperties are not
>   supported for actions that are not used for client-side extensions.'

This is the code for the creation of the UserCustomAction:

```
...
// var colCustomActions = cc.Web.UserCustomActions; // << also tried in the web
var colCustomActions = cc.Site.UserCustomActions;
var newCustomAction = colCustomActions.Add();                
newCustomAction.ClientSideComponentId = new Guid(guidFromTheManifest);
newCustomAction.ClientSideComponentProperties = "";
newCustomAction.Update();
cc.ExecuteQueryRetry();
```

Any hints?
Do you have an example of the code for the creation of the UserCustomAction?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was missing, the location property:

```
newCustomAction.Location = "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer";
```

:)